# Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript

Tags: macros, subscripts

I would like to redefine the underscore `_` to automatically set subscripts in math mode in roman type, as I currently find myself almost always using `_\mathrm{}`. I can't find a way of redefining what `_` does:
 `\renewcommand_` gives

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible
```

and `\show_` just tells me

```
subscript character _.
```

I found [a description of how to make `_` an active character](http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/SubscriptAndSuperscriptInTextMode) on Anthony Lieken's website, but that just brings `_` and `^` to text mode and does not change the behaviour in math mode.

Question:
How do I make `_x` behave like `_\mathrm{x}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Making `_` active was the right idea:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
a_{text} $a_{text}$
\end{document}
```

Thanks to `\ensuremath` (and to Bruno) this can also be used in text mode. For the "old" `_` you can then use `\sb`.

Comment: And to write a normal subscript, you can use `\sb`. Also, if you write `\ensuremath{\sb{\textrm{#1}}}`, you have the added benefit of being able to use it in text mode.

Comment: After some testing, I would prefer `\mathrm` over `\textrm`: it scales better, for instance when writing `$\sum\sb{n=n_{min}}\sp{n_{max}}$`.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm too tired today. Jake explicitly asked for `\mathrm`. You should have written this answer ...

Comment: @Bruno, a late comment: If you load `amsmath`, then `\mathrm` and `\textrm` scale the same, but still, `\mathrm` is better since it gives the same output in an italic context.

Comment: Since `\mathrm` and `\text` are very common as subscript. What I did recently was to "overload" the unicode character `⌄` to do just this (I also added a shortcut, control-altGR+"-" to type it) and added the code `\catcode⌄ PRIMECHAR =\active
\newcommand⌄[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}` or `...\text{...` (needs `xelatex`)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\catcode`\_=\active
\def_#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

$f_{bar}$ f_x

\[ \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x \]
\[ \int\sb{a}^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Herbert! Could you explain why you would use `\def` in this case instead of `\newcommand`? Am I right in assuming that that's the only difference to Hendrik's/Bruno's answer?

Comment: @Jake: a matter of taste ... A personal decision, when working on TeX level I always use `\def` to make things clear, that it is no LaTeX specific code I am changing. And sometimes I am too lazy for typing long command names ... :-)