# Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript without breaking file names

Tags: macros, subscripts

I've been using Hendrik Vogt's answer to my earlier question [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript), in which he explained how to make the underscore character active and assign a macro to it so that it can be redefined to produce roman type in subscripts:

```
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}
```

The solution works like a charm in maths and text environments, however I've run into trouble when I use it in 'literal' environments, such as file names or references, where making `_` active breaks things.

**Question:** How can I make the underscore produce roman subscript, yet still function as a normal character in file names, labels, references and the like? I only need the subscript function in maths environments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
$D_H$
\label{sec_a} % This causes a "! Missing \endcsname inserted." error
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need the `_` in math, then `\mathcode` does the trick. However, TeX seems to see the `\catcode` before the `\mathcode`, so I changed that, too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \gdef_#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}
\endgroup
\mathcode`\_=\string"8000
\catcode`\_=12

\begin{document}
$D_H$
\label{sec_a} % This no longer causes a "! Missing \endcsname inserted." error
\end{document}
```

For simplicity I used `\gdef` here; this can be avoided if you want to.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Your original solution has already saved me so much typing, and I'm glad I don't have to stop using it because of the file name issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can test for mathmode using `\ifmmode` like `\ensuremath` is doing it.
This should then be done with two macros so that the "normal underscore" doesn't take an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{_}{\ifmmode\expandafter\sbrm\else\string_\fi}
\newcommand{\sbrm}[1]{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_test.tex}
   Read input file test Test!
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\label{sec_a} % Works now
$D_H$

\input{\jobname_test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional approach (and the `filecontents` environment, that'll definitely come in handy)!

Comment: @Jake: Note that without loading the `filecontents` *package* the environment does not overwrite existing files.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Your solution is causing troubles using greek in the subscript (like `$H_{\alpha}$`). Adding an extra `\ensuremath` solves that: \catcode`_=\active \newcommand{}[1]{\ifmmode\expandafter\ensuremath{\sb{\mathsf{#1}}}\else\string\fi} Anyway, Hendriks approach works out of the box for greek subscript.

Answer (score 1):

You need not necessarily name labels like that (try `\label{sec:a}`), and for filenames or other use cases force `_` to be an ordinary character:

```
\input{file\string_name}
```

Comment: Actually, `\_` does this - or not ?