# Short form for textup in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using simple quotes “” instead of \text{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/using-simple-quotes-instead-of-text)

For subscripts I usally use `\textup` but if you have many of them it's much to write and read.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The density of water is $\rho_{\textup{Water}} = \SI{1.0}{kg\per d\cubic m}$.
\end{document}
```

So instead of that, similar to the new formular editor of Word, I'd like to write:

```
$\rho_"Water"$
```

or

```
$\rho__{Water}$
```

But I prefer the first version because it is more flexible you could also write:

```
$x_{"Person",i}$
```

Is there a package that provides something like that? I have seen this question: [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript without breaking file names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript-without-breaking-file-names), but I don't want to change the default behavior for indices/subscripts.

Comment: Have you seen [Using simple quotes "" instead of \text{}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38008)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, no I haven't. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Aside from the markup syntax it is probably better to use `\mathrm` rather than `\textup` to be consistent with other uses of roman font on math expressions (rather than use the possibly different text font family current outside the expression)

Comment: @quinmars In [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94753/21930) he links to [this document](http://data.imf.au.dk/system/latex/bog/version3/beta/ltxb-2011-09-13-20-10.pdf) which, in page 269 it shows how to achieve something similar (Kodetip 10.1). I don't understand danish but seeing the example it works perfect (I substituted `\textup` by `\mathrm`).

Comment: @Manuel, thanks for the tip. This works even better. The quote version doesn't work for me. I think it clashs with babel or another package.

Comment: @quinmars It doesn't work as `$x_{"Person",i}$`, but it works pretty well like `x_|Person|`. I discovered a few days ago. Moreover, it doesn't chage the meaning of `|`, only if you put it on a sub/sup script.