# Redefine underscore to produce upright-shape subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, subscripts, underscore

I want to have upright-shape subscripts while in math mode and that by default, i.e. I want to redefine the underscore _

I have found a solution for that here [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript) but it will also overwrite _ when it is not used in math mode and cause problems, for example when including a figure that has an underscore in the name.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I found the answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript-without-breaking-file-names?rq=1

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to clarify that what you want is upright-shaped glyphs in subscript positions. The term "roman" is, in my opinion, unnecessarily confusing since some fonts provide both slanted-Roman as well as upright-Roman glyphs, along with both slanted-italic and upright-italic [yes, there is such a thing] glyphs.

Comment: See also [Non-italic (roman) subscripts in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466411/5001).