# Redefine underscore on a per command basis.

Tags: macros, subscripts

Is it possible to redefine the underscore while within a particular command only?  This is somewhat related to: [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript)

I would like:

```
\mycmd       -->    S
\mycmd_0     -->    S_{modifier 0}
\mycmd_t     -->    S_{modifier t}
\othercmd_0  -->    X_0
Y_t          -->    Y_t
```

So I want the modification of the underscore to be restricted to \mycmd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to define `\mycmd` the right way.

If `modifier` is a macro that takes an argument (like `\mathrm`), then you can simply do the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{%
    S% <- put the actual \mycmd here.
    \@ifnextchar_{_\expandafter\mathrm\@gobble}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

`\@ifnextchar#1#2#3` is a macro from the LaTeX kernel, that simply checks whether the following character is equal to `#1`. If so, it executes `#2`, otherwise `#3`. In our case, we check if `\mycmd` is followed by an underscore (note that any whitespace is removed). If so, then `_\expandafter\mathrm\@gobble` is executed. Here `\mathrm` is the actual `modifier`. We want the underscore before the modifier, so we insert it at the beginning and remove the underscore the user typed with `\@gobble` (`\@gobble` simply removes its argument). The `\expandafter` makes sure that the underscore is removed before `\mathrm` looks for its argument (otherwise `\mathrm` would try to take `\@gobble` as its argument, leading to an error).

If `\modifier` is something that acts like `\itshape` or `\color`, one has to do something slightly more involved in order to get correct grouping:

```
\makeatletter
\def\myothercmd{%
    T%
    \@ifnextchar_{\myothercmd@}{}%
}
\def\myothercmd@_#1{%
    _{{\color{red}#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here the underscore is removed while `\myothercmd@` searches for its argument, which is specified as `_#1`. Then the group after the underscore (i.e. `#1`) is reinserted together with an underscore and the the modifier in front of it. Of course this solution would also work with a modifier of the first case, e.g. defining `\myothercmd@` as `_{\mathrm{#1}}`.

---

If you also want to allow superscripts, you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{%
    T%
    \@ifnextchar_{\mycmd@d}{\@ifnextchar^{\mycmd@u}{}}%
}
\def\mycmd@d_#1{%
    _{{\color{red} #1}}%
    \@ifnextchar^{\mycmd@u}{}%
}
\def\mycmd@u^#1{%
    ^{\mathrm{#1}}%
    \@ifnextchar_{\mycmd@d}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Very nice, but isn't this fragile to the order at which you specify the underscore.  It would not work if I did:  $\mycmd^3_2$.

Comment: @Tom: You can test if next character is `^` and make similar definitions.

Comment: @Tom: See updated answer. Also I noticed that super- and subscripts are typeset in the same group. So the switch-like modifiers (e.g. `\color`) need an extra group.