# Problem with newly defined command and special chars

Tags: macros, errors

I have the following problem. In my document, I defined a new command to save a few chars

```
\renewcommand{\r}{r_\mathrm{max}}
```

Additionally, since it is Swedish, it makes use of the special char å, which is actually given by `\aa` in LaTeX
.
However, my newly defined command somehow seems to destroy the command `\aa`. I get the message that a `missing $ was inserted` and than the `\aa` somehow seems to get replaced by the `r_max`.

I assume the problem is that `\r` is already that circle above, and that's why it gets messed up. Unfortunately, my thesis is already done (except for the Swedish abstract), and I used `\r` quite often, so I would prefer to not change it everywhere. Is there a solution for my problem?

Here is a complete non-working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\renewcommand{\r}{r_\mathrm{max}}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\title{Brief Article} 
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

asdasds $\r$ \aa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Typing `\show\aa` shows that `\aa` is defined as `\r a` which is causing the problem.  I'm not sure how you can maintain your use of `\r` however.

Comment: I didn't know that `\aa` was the same as `\r a`.  Is there some similar transiteration for `\l`?  If so, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript) for a way to type `r_{max}` and get the same result as if you had typed `r_\mathrm{max}` (that could be helpful if you also need to typeset other variable names with roman subscripts).

Comment: Apart from the real issue (redefining `\r`), I suggest *not* using such shorthands: `\rmax` would be a better choice from a semantic point of view (and is not much more difficult to type).

Comment: search/replace in your editor should allow changing painlessly `\r` into the `\rmax` of `egreg` for example.

Comment: @jfbu Of course being careful not to break things like `\renewcommand`, `\ref`, `\right` etc.

Comment: @ScottH. sure. Hopefully the OP's editor understands regex's so it's pretty easy then to look for the string `\r` not immediately followed by a letter which would signal a control sequence...

Answer (score 9):

I strongly recommend not to redefine such basic macros like `\accents`. This causes trouble such as you has experienced.

If `\aa` and `\AA` are the only macros that use the ring accent `\r`, then
you can redefine them. Our example file uses font encoding `OT`. The line below would be used for encoding `T1`.

```
\DeclareTextAccent{\ring}{OT1}{23}
% \DeclareTextAccent{\ring}{T1}{6}
\renewcommand*{\aa}{\ring a}
\renewcommand*{\AA}{\ring A}
```

`\r` is also used, if `å` is directly used (option `latin1` for package
`inputenc`).
Assuming that you are not changing the encoding, this can be fixed:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\DeclareInputText{197}{\r A}
\DeclareInputText{229}{\r a}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout op
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ...
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\renewcommand{\r}{r_\mathrm{max}}

\DeclareTextAccent{\ring}{OT1}{23}
\renewcommand*{\aa}{\ring a}
\renewcommand*{\AA}{\ring A}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\DeclareInputText{197}{\r A}
\DeclareInputText{229}{\r a}

\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

asdasds $\r$ \aa

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great, that works, thank you. I obviously will not use such short commands anymore. I just didn't know that \r was actually already used. And since it is a complete thesis with over 100 pages, replacing all \r's and checking if it was correctly done would have been a lot of work. So you really saved me some time, thanks

Comment: @Chris You have `\renewcommand{\r}{...}`, so you knew that `\r` is already defined. As a general rule, never use `\renewcommand` if you don't know what the already defined command does. My usual example is `\renewcommand{\fi}{...}`: the number of errors will amaze you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into LaTeX kernel `latex.ltx`, you will find there the lines

```
\def \aa {\r a}
\def \AA {\r A}
```

As you see, ring accent (`\r`) is used in the definition of `\aa` and `\AA`.

It is a bad idea to renew LaTeX commands.  You may want to define `\myr` instead. Just use your text editor to change `\r` to `\myr`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the LaTeX kernel `latex.ltx` has the lines

```
\def \aa {\r a}
\def \AA {\r A}
```

you need to do something like

```
\let\ringaccent\r
\def\aa{\ringaccent a}
\def\aa{\ringaccent a}
```

before you redefine `\r`.

I disagree with the opinion that it is quite generally a bad idea to overwrite plain TeX or LaTeX commands. In math typing, you may have excellent reasons to use one-letter macros like `\r` or `\v`. Reserving them for rarely or never used accents would be wasteful. Reserving them for just two lines of LaTeX internals would be ridiculous. TeX was meant to give us flexibility; let's use it.