# Make subscript size smaller (always)

Tags: subscripts

I have a file with a lot of subscripts everywhere and I would like to make them more compact.

I can define  `\ms` with `\newcommand{\ms}{\scriptscriptstyle}`

How can I redefine

```
_{}
```

so that it it applies a `\ms` (without having to type it every time, i.e., so that

```
_{} := _{\ms }
```

EDIT with usecase:

The reason I am looking for this is that what I am writing contains a lot of subscripting of the form

```
x_{i+k,t}
```

it has to be reported, but I feel most times to be cumbersome and unappealing to the eyes. A lot of the times it can be skipped while reading, so I just wanted to make it standout less.

Comment: See the answer by David Carlisle on how to change the font-size (which is what you want to do), in case you really want to redefine the meaning of the subscript, see answers e.g. here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not clear why you would want it. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Edited to explain usecase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}

\begin{document}
$A_x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer the question. Coupled with David's answer allows for some finetuning of subscripts. Thanks!

Comment: What's `\ensuremath` for?

Comment: @egreg If you want to use it in text as well. That was not so clear from the question. Does not hurt in any case.

Answer (score 8):

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{3}{3}

\begin{document}

aa $V_1 V_2 $

\end{document}
```

3pt is rather small, just used to exaggerate the effect, the standard sizes 
are 7 and 5 so you could use `{10}{10}{5}{5}` (in which case you would not need
the `fix-cm` package which is just used to allow the font to be scaled to arbitrary sizes)

The standard sizes (display, text, script and scriptscript) set by latex are:

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it alters my superscript as well. I am in fact using yours and @LaRiFaRi answer to achieve the desired result(I make subscripting smaller by default, and tune how small I want it by tweaking the /scriptscriptstyle size). This is probably not best in general, but suits the notation required by my current work. Thanks !

Comment: What do the {\@xpt} do?

Comment: @ThreeDiag `\@xpt` is 10pt, such abbreviations are used all over the latex sources (and save a few bytes that needed saving back then)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a very bad idea. This said, here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{_{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`_="8000 \catcode`_=12 }

\begin{document}

New: $A_1^2$

Original: $A_{\scriptstyle1}^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you are right that this is a bad idea in general. For the small report I need to write (where I don't expect to have other math environment requiring a different treatment) it should be alright.