# Make superscript size smaller (always)

Tags: tex-core, superscripts

How would you implement the "catcode" solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262295/make-subscript-size-smaller-always) for superscripts? Thanks

EDIT

The code below reproduces the error (complied using XeLaTeX). Works if the following two lines are commented out:

```
\catcode`^=\active
\newcommand^[1]{\ensuremath{\sp{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,no-math]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.8in,bmargin=0.8in,lmargin=0.8in,rmargin=0.8in}



\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}

\catcode`^=\active
\newcommand^[1]{\ensuremath{\sp{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}


\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}


\section{Set up}

\begin{align*}
\int_{n-1}^{n}c_{n}dt & =x\left(i,n\right)\\
\implies c_{n} & =x\left(i,n\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just copy the code replacing `_` by `^`  and `\sb` by `\sp`

Comment: Thanks, David. I did that, but it didn't work for some reason. 

\catcode`^=\active
\newcommand^[1]{\ensuremath{\sp{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}

Comment: if you want help with an error message the question is always clearer if it includes a complete test document that produces the error and the exact error message you got. "did not work" is hard to debug.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.1455 \XC@catcodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes because you're changing category codes before TeX processes certain files that don't expect those category codes:

```
\catcode`^=\active
\newcommand^[1]{\ensuremath{\sp{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

This means that `xcolor.sty` is processed with the new catcode for `^` (not something it is prepared for), which can lead to undesirable results. Similar problems with having this redefinition before `\usepackage{xunicode}`.

Move these `\catcode`-changing lines to after all external files have been loaded. Say, just before or after `\begin{document}`. Then the error goes away.