# Making Text under alphabet bigger Mathode

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How to make the letters under **V** bigger, I'm using 10pt on A5 paper in my original document and it's unreadable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    $V_{a bc defg}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262296/31034

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not really trying to typeset `$V_{a bc defg}$`. Please provide a more realistic example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked, "How to make the letters under V bigger"? I assume you mean, "as big as the letter V itself". If this assumption is correct, and if you also intend letters in subscript position to continue to be rendered in math-italic mode, you can use a `\textstyle` directive at the start of the subscript block; see the code below.

That said, it's typographic custom to typeset math-style subscript and superscript material ca 30% smaller than the material on the baseline (here: the single letter "V").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$V_{abcdefgVVV}$

$V_{\textstyle abcdefgVVV}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

in normalize and upright:

```
$V_{\mbox{a bc defg}}$
```