# Redefine ^ to produce roman superscripts and subscripts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, subscripts, superscripts, roman

I need to set subscripts and superscripts automatically in mathematical equations in roman font style for a book publication. I do not want to apply `\mathrm{...}` to each subscript or superscript separately.

Fortunately I found a solution to globally set subscripts in roman font style in [Redefine underscore to produce roman subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript). I made a slight adaptation in order to have all indexes in sequence in roman font style:

```
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\ensuremath{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}}
```

Original typeset `$x_{abc}^{de}$`:  [image: original]

Roman subscripts with code above `$x_{abc}^{de}$`:  [image: roman subscript]

I can, however, not figure out how to apply this code to superscripts. Does anyone have a solution so set both the subscript and superscript font style to roman?

Comment: can't you just replace `_` by `^` and `\sb` by `\sp` ?

Comment: I assume you never raise to the power of a variable, and instead only use descriptive superscripts in your field?  Because in `$x \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{x}}$` the two `x`s are different entities, while in  `$x \mathrm{e}^x$` they're not.

Comment: Correct, I only use descriptive superscripts.

Answer (score 6):

I fail to see the rationale for this, however here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\upsub}[1]{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\upsup}[1]{\sp{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\let~\upsub}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`^\lowercase{\endgroup\let~\upsup}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`_=12 \catcode`^=12
  \mathcode`_="8000
  \mathcode`^="8000
}

\begin{document}

$x_{abc}^{de}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really hope this is because it's a book about a field that only uses *descriptive* text superscripts rather than powers.  I've come across this but can;t recall what uses it.

Comment: @egreg, thanks a lot for your solution. It works very well for me.

Comment: The (German) publisher insists on roman subscripts and superscripts. So the only choice I have is to either manually re-format (some older) LaTeX code use this trick to globally change the format.

Comment: @christiankral If the publisher tells me that `$x_{n}$` must have the “n” in upright type, I tell them they don't know about mathematics. Of course, this depends on *what* the subscripts/superscripts contain.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the package [altsubsup](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/altsubsup) to implement the solution given by egreg as bracket forms of `_` and `^`.
See:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{altsubsup}

\begin{document}

$ x_[roman]^{italic} \quad x_{italic}^[roman] \quad
  x_[roman]^[roman]  \quad x_{italic}^{italic}  $

\end{document}
```

[image: code with altsubsup package]

Bracket forms are displayed using `\text`, but this can be customized.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It doesn't change the catcodes of `_` and `^`. Instead, it sets up a Lua function and assigns it to the `process_input_buffer` callback; that way, all instances of `_{...}` and `^{...}` are converted to `_{\mathrm{...}}` and `^{\mathrm{...}}`, respectively, *before* LaTeX even starts its usual processing.

Whitespace between `_`/`^` and the material enclosed in curly braces is OK. However, the presence of the curly braces is significant: the Lua function will *not* modify the appearance of `y^x` and `x_n`, say.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function make_roman ( s )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "_%s-(%b{})",  "_{\\mathrm%1}" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "%^%s-(%b{})", "^{\\mathrm%1}" )
  return s 
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
  "process_input_buffer", make_roman , "make_roman" )}}

\begin{document}
$x_{abc}^ {de}$ 
\end{document}
```