# How to define a new character while avoiding clashes with existing character definitions?

Tags: catcodes, active-characters

I want to define a new **character**.  For context, in particular, my new character would act similar to the `^` character for superscripts, but would put parentheses around the context of the superscript.

I know that I could write a **normal command**, like

`\newcommand{\superscriptWithParentheses}[2]{{#1}^{({#2})}}`

which produce the desired result.  For instance, `\superscriptWithParentheses{x}{i}` would successfully create `x^{(i)}`. But  I am hoping to define a character instead of an ordinary command.  Why?  For the same reasons that people would prefer to write `x_i` instead of `x\sp{i}`.  (Basically, my motivations have to do with the (1) readability of the source code when the arguments get complex and (2) syntactic consistency with similar operators `_` and `^`.   I could provide a concrete example if the additional motivation is necessary.)

Now following [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript), if I wanted to **redefine** `^`, I could do

```
\catcode`\^=\active
\newcommand{^}[1]{\sp{({#1})}}
```

However, I want to keep the `^` character for normal superscript usage.

So it seems like I need to define a new character.  But which one? I can't think of one that doesn't already have a meaning that I shouldn't overwrite.   Does anybody have advice?  Is there some character that would be good to use that I'm not considering? Is there some way to provide a special meaning to double characters, like `^^`?  Is there some way to define `\^` as a character that has different meaning than `^`?  Is there some other approach I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can define

```
\def\^#1{^{(#1)}}
```

and use `a\^{b+c}` which expands to `a^{(a+c)}`. But there is a problem with old 8-bit LaTeX and its LICR (LaTeX internal character representation) where `\^` is expected as accent-crating macro: `\^o` expands to `ô`. More exactly, if you redefine `\^` and use old 8-bit LaTeX, then: if a user write `ô` in the input file, it expands internally to `\^o` and the following expansion crashes if `\^` is redefined. So, you have to use a new LaTeX, i.e. LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Or you can leave LaTeX completely and use OpTeX, for example.

Egreg showed classical solution for `^^` and he tried to compare it with Expl3 macros. I see the Expl3 code much more cryptic, but this is opinion based. If you are using OpTeX then you can use following code for `^^` and you can compare:

```
\adef^{\ea\isnextchar \string^{\spb}{\sp}}
\def\spb#1#2{\sp{(#2)}}
\mathcode`\^="8000 \catcode`\^=12

$ a^^b, \quad c^d $

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I recommend it, but you can make `^` math active. In math mode, `^` will check for an immediately following `^`; in this case it parenthesizes the superscript, otherwise it just emits a normal superscript token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ashman_hat:w
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF ^
   {% there is ^, remove it and do
    \__ashman_hat_double:n
   }
   {% else, just normal ^
    \c_math_superscript_token
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ashman_hat_double:n
 {
  \c_math_superscript_token { (#1) }
 }

\char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__ashman_hat:w

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^="8000 \catcode`^=12 }

\begin{document}

$a^b+a^^b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This has no consequence on the text mode accent `\^`.

The “classical” code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ashman@hat}{\futurelet\ashman@next\ashman@@hat}
\newcommand{\ashman@@hat}{%
  \if\noexpand\ashman@next\string^%
    \expandafter\ashman@hathat
  \else
    \expandafter\sp
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\ashman@hathat}[2]{\sp{(#2)}}

\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\global\let^\ashman@hat
\endgroup

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^="8000 \catcode`^=12 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a^b+a^^b$

\end{document}
```

Not shorter and more cryptic.

If you find a way to easily key in `↑` then you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{↑}{\ashmanparens}
\newcommand{\ashmanparens}[1]{^{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

$a^b+a↑b$

\end{document}
```

All methods work with any TeX engine (except Knuth TeX, for which only the “classical” method works).

Comment: I like that $a^b$ and $a^^b$ give different behaviors.  But just curious, why don't you recommend it?  Is there a potential for this to cause large problems that I'm not thinking about?  If so, how would you personally handle my situation?

Comment: @ashman I’d type `a^{(b)}`, that’s all. 